# ComboBox hidden behind Button not triggering on Click event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb6-migration

I'm converting an old VB form to .NET, and there a few Buttons which each have a corresponding ComboBox hiding behind them.  The previous behavior was that you'd click the Button, and that would trigger the ComboBox behind it, which would then drop down a selection list.  I believe the idea was to have a static color and text label *(which cannot be a selectable option in the drop-down list)*, with the functionality of a ComboBox.

Now, in VB.NET, clicking on the Button *(which is directly over the ComboBox in the form)* won't trigger the ComboBox dropdown anymore.  However, if I make the ComboBox visible enough to click on, it will trigger the `ComboBox.TextChanged` event, and show the drop-down *(they're set to the `DropDownList` style)*.  I've set the event handler to handle both that event and the Button event.  I've tried `Button.MouseDown`, `Button.MouseClick`, and `Button.Click` -- none of which have worked.

I did find the SplitButton control option [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10171863/1411373), which would probably do the job, but I don't want to have to integrate a non-native control for just 3 buttons. I don't really want to [mess with the control template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703206/combobox-controltemplate-drop-down-button), either -- and I'm not sure that would be a solution, anyway.

Why is the ComboBox not triggering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to visualy do. But you can set the [`ComboBox.DroppedDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.droppeddown) Property to True in your Button Click Event to trigger the DropDown. Which should look like this.

[image]

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to have a ComboBox with a static appearance.  This was previously "faked" by hiding the ComboBox behind a button, and triggering the drop-down when the button was clicked.

Comment: @Wingman4l7 I just added an Image is that what you are wanting?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for; that solution sounds like it should work, but I'm testing it and it doesn't seem to.  I'm still curious as to why a control "behind" another control wouldn't trigger when a click occurs within its location.

Comment: @Wingman4l7 The Button handles the Click Event and the ComboBox never sees it. I just put ComboBox1.DroppedDown = True in the Button click event and it worked. What you are wanting is more like routed events in WPF

Comment: @Wingman4l7 To further explain what is going on look at this [CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13216/Broadcasting-Events-through-a-Control-Hierarchy)

Comment: It looks like the ComboBox will display the drop-down upon clicking, regardless of whether or not it has an event handler for it; interesting.  This solution does what I need; thanks!